# Dynamically change the transformation of a QML element

Tags: qt, qml

It took quite some time for me to figure out a problem I had about rotating a QML object, so I decided to share this.

The question:
How can I dynamically update the rotation of a QML element (like image). I know I can set, e.g. the rotation using a transformation (in the example of a MapQuickItem):

```
MapQuickItem
{
    sourceItem: Image
    {
        id: image
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        source: "image.png"
        sourceSize.width:  Screen.devicePixelRatio * 256
        sourceSize.height: Screen.devicePixelRatio * 256
        transform: Rotation { 
            origin { x: image.sourceSize.width/2; 
                     y: image.sourceSize.height/2; 
                     z: 0} 
            angle: 0
        }
    }
}
```

However, how can I update the angle (or other parts of the `transform`) dynamically?

Answer (score 3):

A cleaner way to do it would be using a property or an alias:

```
MapQuickItem
{
    sourceItem: Image
    {
        id: image

        property alias rotationAngle: rotation.angle

        anchors.centerIn: parent
        source: "image.png"
        sourceSize.width:  Screen.devicePixelRatio * 256
        sourceSize.height: Screen.devicePixelRatio * 256
        transform: Rotation { 
            id: rotation
            origin { x: image.sourceSize.width/2; 
                     y: image.sourceSize.height/2; 
                     z: 0} 
            angle: 0
        }
    }
}
```

with:

```
function updatePositionAndRotation(angleDeg)
{
    image.rotationAngle = angleDeg
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The key information was that `transform` is actually a list of transformations.

So one possible solution to the above question is a function like this (e.g. changing the rotation):

```
function updateRotation(angleDeg)
{
    image.transform[0].angle = angleDeg;
}
```